# Should questions about peripherals or accessories be allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should we allow questions about peripherals or accessories? From our currently proposed FAQ.

> Questions about the following things are off-topic:
>
> - Purchasing of the device or its accessories

To be clear, the definitions of these terms are.

**Peripheral**

> A peripheral is a device connected to a host computer, but not part of it, and is more or less dependent on the host. These are also input/output devices.

**Accessory**

> A thing that can be added to something else in order to make it more useful, versatile, or attractive.

We already have [a question dealing with peripherals](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/113/46), so I think it is time to ask. Should we allow questions about peripherals, accessories, or both?

Answer (score 2):

## Peripherals Only

Questions about peripherals should only be allowed. To be clear, a peripheral is a device such as a sensor or dongle that extends the capability of the Raspberry Pi. These are different from accessories, as an accessory is a device that deals with the appearance of the Raspberry Pi.

Some examples of a question about peripherals would be.

1. What is a WiFi dongle that is able to interface with Arch Linux?
2. What is a HDMI touchscreen that is able to interface with Debian?

Some examples of a question about accessories would be.

1. What cases are available?
2. Where can I create a custom case?

I think that [RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) would benefit more from the first set of questions than the second set. And as long as the questions aren't **subjective**, as in there is no "correct" answer, then [RaspberryPi.SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) would benefit from questions about certain peripherals.

Comment: I slightly disagree. Cases specifically could affect performance if not properly constructed (grounding, scraping solder joints, etc). However, I see the value in not getting a bunch of threads with pictures of people's cases asking what color LED they should put on their Lego Darth Vader

Comment: @KyleMacey So would you consider a question like, "What should I keep in my mind when designing a case?", on topic?

Comment: I suppose, yes. The basics and obvious things should be covered, since not everyone on here is going to be an expert. So stuff like "make sure you cut holes for all your connectors" really isn't that far-fetched to someone who has never made a case before (just an example, may not *that* radical)

Comment: I think it is a shame not to be able to share a good experience of a product. For instance, I would like to spread my opinion about a good case I bought because it is cheap, and really fits well the RPi. Even though it is subjective, it could help people to find quality products. Maybe we should start a wiki on the subject (if not already done)?